# Regex to match specific domain and it's subfolder

Tags: regex

I want to match a particular domain and its subdomain, no matter how it's entered. In the following example, I want to match all ´test.com`if nothing comes after it (only a slash or query strings) OR if a specific folder follows it in this case it's named as:`subfolder`. Again the subfolder could have / or query strings after.

| Domain | Match |
| --- | --- |
| test.com | match |
| https://test.com | match |
| https://test.com?foo=bar | match |
| https://test.com/ | match |
| https://test.com/?foo=bar | match |
| https://www.test.com | match |
| https://www.test.com/subfolder | match |
| https://www.test.com/subfolder/ | match |
| https://www.test.com/subfolder/?foo=bar | match |
| test.com/subfolder | match |
| https://www.test.com/foo | no match |
| test.com/foo | no match |
| https://www.test.com/jason | no match |
| https://www.test.com/jason?foo=bar | no match |

Right now I have the following regex:

```
^(?:\S+://)?[^/]+/?$
```

The problem though is that it matches ANY domains, which is not what I need. I want to match a specific domain and a specific subfolder.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?test\.com(?:/subfolder)?/?(?:\?\S*)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9H3lWl/2)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:https?://)?: *optionally* match` http://`or`https://`
- `(?:www\.)?`: *optionally* match `www.`
- `test\.com`: match `test.com`
- `(?:/subfolder)?`: *optionally* match `/subfolder`
- `/?`: *optionally* match a trailing `/`
- `(?:\?\S*)?`: *optionally* match query string starting with `?`
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
^(?:(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?)?test\.com(?:(?:(?:\/)?(?:\/subfolder\/?)?(?:\/\?\S+\/?)?)?(?:\?\S+)?)?(?:\/)?$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/ko4Ndo/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^                            ##Starting of match here by caret sign.
(?:                          ##Starting non-capturing group here.
   (?:https?:\/\/)           ##In this non-capturing group which has http/https// in it to match.
   (?:www\.)?                ##In this non-capturing group keeping www. as an optional here.
)?                           ##Closing very first non-capturing group here.
test\.com                    ##Matching string test.com here. (1, calling it 1 for explanation purposes)
(?:                          ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
   (?:                       ##Starting one more non-capturing group here.(2, calling it for explanation purposes only)
      (?:\/)?                ##Matching / optional in a non-capturing group here.
      (?:\/subfolder\/?)?    ##Matching /subfolder /(as optional) and whole non-capturing group as optional.
      (?:\/\?\S+\/?)?        ##Matching /? and all non-space characters followed by /(optional) in non-capturing group, keep this optional.
   )?                        ##Closing (2) non-capturing group here.
   (?:                       ##Starting non-capturing group here.
      \?\S+                  ##Matching ? non-spaces values here.
   )?                        ##Closing non-capturing group here.
)?                           ##Closing (1) non-capturing group here.
(?:                          ##Starting non-capturing group here.
   \/                        ##Matching single / here.
)?                           ##Closing non-capturing group here, keeping it optional.
$                            ##Mentioning $ to tell the end of value(match).
```